# MSBuild not copying files to the publish folder?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild

I have a .net framework MVC project, it is purely generated by visual studio as it's sample project.

When I publish it using Visual Studio 2019 it works perfect, all the web views and dlls are published to destination folder (bin\app.publish).

In order to test the CI/CD pipeline on Jenkins, I tried to use MSBuild to publish in command line following some samples from Microsoft, but it only performs compiling and no files have been published to destination folder.

My command and publishprofile is like below, can anyone let me know what is wrong with it?

```
msbuild jenkins1.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=default
```

default.pubxml

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>bin\app.publish</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The building output is like below, I deleted some duplicate lines to make it short and clear.

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.1+3e40a09f8 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 23/12/2021 3:20:32 PM.
Project "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\jenkins1.csproj" on node 1 (Rebuild target(s)).
CoreClean:
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\jenkins1.dll".
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\jenkins1.pdb".
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\csc.exe".
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\csc.exe.config".
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\csc.rsp".
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\csi.exe".
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\csi.exe.config".
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\csi.rsp".
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.CodeAnalysis.dll".
  Deleting file "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll".
  ....................


GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the i
nput files.
CoreCompile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:17
  01,1702 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:DEBUG;TRACE /highentropyva+ /reference:C:\Users\mdu
  an\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Antlr.3.5.0.2\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins
  2\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompi
  lerPlatform.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Micr
  osoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\n
  et40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NE
  TFramework\v4.7.2\mscorlib.dll" /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2\lib\n
  et45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4
  .7.2\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Fra
  mework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Configuration.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microso
  ft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\
  Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemb
  lies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblie
  s\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Micros
  oft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Micros
  oft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemb
  lies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assem
  blies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Ref
  erence Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Web.Abstractions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files
  (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll" /reference:"C
  :\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Pr
  ogram Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Web.DynamicData.dll" /referenc
  e:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Web.Entity.dll" /refer
  ence:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
   /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Helper
  s.dll /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dl
  l /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.W
  eb.Optimization.dll /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.7\lib\net45\S
  ystem.Web.Razor.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\
  System.Web.Routing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.
  7.2\System.Web.Services.dll" /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7
  \lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.AspN
  et.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsof
  t.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assembli
  es\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\M
  icrosoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages
  \WebGrease.1.6.0\lib\WebGrease.dll /debug+ /debug:full /optimize- /out:obj\Debug\jenkins1.dll /subsystemversion:6.00
  /target:library /utf8output /langversion:7.3 App_Start\BundleConfig.cs App_Start\FilterConfig.cs App_Start\RouteConfi
  g.cs Controllers\HomeController.cs Global.asax.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "obj\Debug\.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2.
  AssemblyAttributes.cs"
  CompilerServer: server - server processed compilation - 2acabf12-862a-4309-a66c-f79b85daae60
_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
  Copying file from "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Micro
  soft.Web.Infrastructure.dll" to "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  " to "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2
  .0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll" to "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\M
  icrosoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll".
 .................................


CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\obj\Debug\jenkins1.dll" to "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenki
  ns2\bin\jenkins1.dll".
  jenkins1 -> C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\jenkins1.dll
  Copying file from "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\obj\Debug\jenkins1.pdb" to "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenki
  ns2\bin\jenkins1.pdb".


CopyRoslynCompilerFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Copying file from "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2
  .0.1\tools\roslynlatest\csi.exe" to "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\csi.exe".
  Copying file from "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2
  .0.1\tools\roslynlatest\csc.exe" to "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\csc.exe".
  Copying file from "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2
  .0.1\tools\roslynlatest\csc.rsp" to "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\bin\roslyn\csc.rsp".
 .................................


Done Building Project "C:\Users\mduan\source\repos\jenkins2\jenkins1.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)).


Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.51
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved by installing a NuGet package: `MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets`

Previously the `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` in project file having some problems, so it cannot publish correctly.